# Is there a way to use any font you want?

Tags: jquery, css

An SVG alphabet and characters. You do a display:none until the characters are converted? No crazy plugins to make it happen.

Comment: any font in just css or some jquery or svg magic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [`@font-face`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp)?

Comment: bingo, better than what i wanted.